# Why is this selenium script (on IE11) not working after Thread.sleep(7000);

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

```
             WebElement user = driver1.findElement(By.id("usrname"));
user.sendKeys("username");
System.out.println("Username entered");

WebElement password = driver1.findElement(By.id("usrpwd"));
password.sendKeys("password");
System.out.println("password entered");

WebElement submit = driver1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ibm-pcon']/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/input[1]"));
submit.click();
System.out.println("submit button entered");

Thread.sleep(7000); 

WebElement role = driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='userRole'][@value='ARCOL '][@type='radio'][@name='role']"));
role.click();
System.out.println("role entered");
```

> It is not able to find the element in web page by.xpath.
>   Till thread.sleep() method code is running fine, but after that it is throwing error.
>   Error:
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: 
>   Unable to find element on closed window 
>   (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Answer (score 0):

```
driver1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ibm-pcon']/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/input[1]"))
```

After you click to element, there could be an iframe / popup on that page.

Try to switch between frames via

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // default frame
driver.switchTo().frame(YOURCURRENTFRAME);
```

Comment: Here we are not using any iframes and for record and playback it is working fine. but with this manual code, it is not able to find element in web page

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use [ExplicitWait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) instead of Thread.sleep();
2. Check driver1.getWindowHandle(); before and after submit.click(); they supposed to be the same.